# Using Superscript and subscript in Telegra.ph editor

Tags: telegram, telegra.ph

Is there support for superscript and subscript HTML Tag formatting in the Telegra.ph editor? There is support for [limited HTML tags](https://telegra.ph/api#NodeElement) at the moment, but is it possible to make use of them directly in the online editor?

Answer (score 0):

for superscript u could use \u00b

for example
i wrote

```
[Ne]3s\u00b2
```

the result is

[Ne]3s2 with "2" superscript

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).